# use Siri intent in react-native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, sirishortcuts

I am going to make a relation between Siri Intent and React-native, but I have an error when I am going to call a class from Intent Extension.
how can I call swift class from different target in Intent Extension. The target of my ReactIntegration.swift is main project which is going to be called from GetCommandIntentHandler.swift (intent extension). Here is the source of two files.

The root and Target of ReactIntegration.swift

[image]
[image]

the source code is

```
import Foundation
@objc(ReactIntegration)
class ReactIntegration: RCTEventEmitter {
  private var count = 0

  @objc
  func AskRequestFromEnergica(request: String) {
     sendEvent(withName: "AskRequestFromEnergica", body: ["request": request])
  }

  override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
    return ["AskRequestFromEnergica"]
  }

  override func constantsToExport() -> [AnyHashable : Any]! {
    return ["initialCount": count]
  }

  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

The target of GetCommandIntentHandler.swift
[image]

the source code is

```
import Foundation

class GetCommandInentHandler: NSObject, GetCommandIntentHandling{
  func handle(intent: GetCommandIntent, completion: @escaping (GetCommandIntentResponse) ->      Void) {
    let req = intent.request!
    let res = "the result is " + req
    let ri = ReactIntegration()
    ri.AskRequestFromEnergica(res);
    let response = GetCommandIntentResponse.success(result: res)
    completion(response)
}
```

the error is 'Cannot find 'ReactIntegration' in scope'.
Please let me know how to solve it. Thanks